# Is there a way to retrieve application layer data on the SDN controller from Mininet hosts?

Tags: controller, mininet, sdn, pox

I would like to send application layer data from a program running on a Mininet host to the SDN Pox controller. Is this possible, or does this break with the SDN paradigm?

Ie. I wish to

```
mininet> h1 python <program that sends data to controller>
```

Comment: What type of data? Have you tried anything?

Comment: It would be JSON data. But seeing as Mininet runs in a virtual network (10.0.0.0/24), and localhost is obviously on my physical network, is there a way to contact the controller anyway? What I basically want to have is an application running on h1 monitoring processes, and notifying the controller when processes go down, so that I can push OF drop rules.

Comment: Check this one, is the reverse of what you want to do but pretty much explains it all. http://pox-dev.noxrepo.narkive.com/8KtfIMxN/can-pox-connect-or-communicate-with-host

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the host (*h1* in this case) sends a message which matches no OpenFlow rules in the switch, it will automatically be send to the controller, as the switch does not know what to do with it. This is the default behavior of OpenFlow/Mininet.

I have previously used this feature to send packets with information regarding the semantic of the sessions to the controller.

Comment: The packet that is sent to the controller, that only contains the information from transportation layer layer and below, no?

Comment: @TheSjiraffen123 As far as I know the whole packet is send. According to the _OpenFlow specification v1.0_: "If no match is found, the packet is forwarded to the controller over the secure channel. The controller is responsible for determining how to handle packets without valid flow entries, and it manages the switch flow table by adding and removing flow entries.".